# How to create a online MeetingParticipantInfo using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create an online Meeting event with participant where I suppose to pass the MeetingParticipants, how to get the IdentitySet from Graph User?

```
List<MeetingParticipantInfo> participantInfos = new List<MeetingParticipantInfo>()
{
    new MeetingParticipantInfo()
    {
        Identity = new IdentitySet(){
            User = graphUser  ??????,
        }
    }
};

MeetingParticipants participants = new MeetingParticipants()
{
    Attendees = participantInfos,
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Charles

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the user details(Id, UPN etc.,) whom you want to include in the online Meeting by specifying the user's UPN(ABC@domain.com) as shown in the below code.

```
public static async Task<OnlineMeeting> CreateOnlineMeeting()
        {
            var User = await graphClient.Users["ABC@domain.com"] // UPN or ID would work 
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            var startDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-02-06T01:49:21.3524945+00:00");

            var endDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-02-06T02:19:21.3524945+00:00");

            var subject = "Create a meeting with customId provided";

            var externalId = "7eb8263f-d0e0-4149-bb1c-1f0476083c56";

            var participants = new MeetingParticipants
            {
                Attendees = new List<MeetingParticipantInfo>()
                {
                    new MeetingParticipantInfo
                    {
                        Identity = new IdentitySet
                        {
                            User = new Identity
                            {
                                Id = User.Id
                            }
                        },
                        Upn = User.UserPrincipalName
                    }
                }
            };

            return await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
                .CreateOrGet(externalId, null, endDateTime, participants, startDateTime, subject)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
    }
```

Comment: If inviting a B2B guest, is it appropriate to use the modified local UPN (#) created in the guest tenant, as the UPN, or should the email address be used along with the OID of the guest user account?